# Searching for all open HTML tags and closing them [PHP]

Tags: php, html, tags

I've got a page on our church website called "The Fridge" which is meant to mimic a fridge where you place sticky notes for information on what's happening in the church.

You can see it here: http://www.ypc.org.au/resources/fridge

Because sticky notes may be various sizes and have more or less information, information over 50 characters is truncated with an ellipses and the rest of the information can be viewed through a modal box by clicking on the note.

This is working fine however tags won't always end properly. 
For instance, If a < p > tag was opened and information in that paragraph was over 50 characters it would be truncated before the paragraph closes.

This is causing invalid HTML and for the colours of the notes (which are being randomised through css) to all be the same colour . Not a huge issue but it would be nice to have valid HTML and have the colours randomised a bit.

What I am wanting to do is search for an open tag, determine what that open tag is and then once 50 characters is reached, end all open tags detected.
I know that won't always be a perfect solution as if a tag is half opened or closed, the user will see that, but it's easy enough to just add or remove a few words
in those cirumstances.

So I am thinking I would need to do something like this (but could be completely wrong; also know its a mix of PHP and pseudo code):

```
REPEAT
    $tag[x]
    Search for the "<" character
    If found {
        go to the next character and append to $tag[x] variable until ">" character is found.
        $x++
    }
UNTIL (NO MORE TAGS FOUND)

Once 50 characters reached (excluding the start tag as user wont see HTML tags), 
see if the tag has been closed.

If the tag has not been closed {
    Echo "<" . $ tag . ">" to end the tag.
}
```

Here is a simple version of how my PHP code is working with some fake information to avoid database connections etc. (Had to do as file as head section wasn't transposing onto page):

http://www.ypc.org.au/fridge.zip

If someone could help with this, it would be much appreciated! It's doing my head in.

Comment: DOMDocument should automatically handle this for you

Comment: You take the wrong approach when trying to fix these damages afterwards. Instead you should prevent them from getting introduced. Instead of simply chopping the markup after 50 characters you should use a DOM parser to chop the real text contained inside the markup text to the limit of 50 chars. Or, even easier, do _not_ chop the text but simply limit the size of the container by means of css and declare the overflowing content as hidden. Same effect, easier implementation, since no content has to be manipulated one by one.

Comment: Thanks arkascha,
Your'e right..I am using the wrong approach for it and it's just complicating it,
I should try and get familair with DOM parsing as I'm still quite new to web development and PHP.
I didn't think about CSS though, that would be the easiest solution to implement and then if needed,
a better solution could be implemented in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for this:

```
$yourText = "<div><span>Text<em>!";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($yourText, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$yourText = $doc->saveHTML();

echo $yourText;
```

**Out:**

```
<div><span>Text<em>!</em></span></div>
```

---

**Edit:** If your text is truncated and it happens to end with something like `<p>This is long text</`, `DOMDocument` will happily strip that truncated tag out and rebuild it. It will raise a *warning* about what it did, however. To suppress that warning you can put `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` prior to `loadHTML()`.

Comment: Thanks heaps Drakes!

That sounds like it would be an easy way to go about it.
Wouldn't have to worry about any complex loops etc as it would
do it all automatically.

Comment: My pleasure. One thing I should add is, if your text is truncated and it ends with something like `</`, this method will strip that out no problem, but it will raise a warning about what it did. To suppress that warning, you can put `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` before `loadHTML()`. Good luck.